# Is it possible to enable WLM for Stored Procedures through DB2 on z/OS

Tags: security, ibm, db2, zos

If core WLM is not available for all built-in Stored Procedures in a DB2 on z/OS, would it be at all possible for a DB2 user with all privileges to setup the core WLM environments through a CLPPlus (or similar) connection to the DB?

I am trying to ascertain if it would be possible for a hacker to compromise our z/OS if they were able to gain full admin access to the DB2 server. This could perhaps be done using something like the ADMIN_COMMAND_UNIX stored procedure.